# How to create POJO from the web service that returns dataset(<Object> any)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, wsdl

Sorry if the below is stupid question, I tried many sites to get the clear response, but since I'm a novice in web service I couldn't understand anything.

I have been given a WSDL file that looks up the server and returns the response in below format

```
<soap:envelop>
    ...
    ..
    <Aresponse>
        <XXXDAtaset>
            <xs:schema>
                <xs:element>
                    <xs:choice>
                        .....
                        .....(Elements are here)

                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
        </XXXDAtaset>
        <diffgr:diffgram>
            <dataset rows>
                -- values are here
            </dataset rows>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
    </Aresponse>
    ..
</soap:envelop>
```

I don't have any POJO to store these values (POJO was not even created when creating client from WSDL). Initial WSDL has `<s:any>` for this response.

How will I create POJO for this SOAP message? I don't know if I have to ask the WSDL provider or any JAXB tools available out there to generate the POJO for this.
I tried this link [How to create java object from 'anyType' returned from service using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080259/how-to-create-java-object-from-anytype-returned-from-service-using-jaxb) but there it seems they already have some POJO to store the response. In my case, I don't have one.

Comment: if you have a valid WSDL, it will contain some XSD. From that any tool (like [CXF codegen](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)) for example will *always* generate POJOs for yo. Otherwise that code would make no sense or even compile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Misa. I searched my initial WSDL but it doest have any XSD, may be it is invalid WSDL? should i need to ask the wsdl provider about the  XSD?

Comment: @jah: how can i find XSD in wsdl.  Im just novice in Webservice. pls  help. thanks in advacne.

Comment: XSD stands for XML Schema.

Answer (score 0):

- Ask your provider for a sample request response soap xml.
- Strip it off the soap envelope,header,body
- You can strip off the namespace too and place it like

  `<someTag xmlns="">` instead of `<xs:someTag>`
      where xs="given namespace"
- use tool/api like [xsd generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) to convert your bare minimum xml to  pojo
- In SOAP protocol header and envelope are rarely changed in a production, as they contain namespace and credentials mainly. So you can write a helper method to append/remove these 'SOAP  components' during marshall/unmarshall

This should help you get started in the right direction.